# 3 columns with list item

Tags: html, css

I want from list items to make 3 column layout. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code with CSS3:

```html
<section class="intro clearself">
      <ul class="three-col-row">
        <li>
          <h2>Wat?..</h2>
          <p>Praktische en juiste informatie is een belangrijke deelsleutel tot de oplossing van rugproblemen.</p>
          <a class="button" href="advice.html">Meer info!</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h2>Hoe...</h2>
          <p>Ga zo ver mogelijk in de beweging en herhaal dit regelmatig gedurende U capaciteit.</p>
          <a class="button" href="work-out.html">Kies je sport!</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h2>Doel...</h2>
          <p>Het belangrijkste aspect is echter dat U ontdekt dat U ZELF veel kan doen om uiteindelijk uw rugklacht te vermijden, meer dan U welicht denkt.</p>
          <a class="button" href="about.html">Meer info!</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

CSS3:

```css
.clearself:before,.clearself:after{
content: " "; 
display: block; 
height: 0; 
overflow: hidden;
}
.clearself:after{clear: both;}
.clearself{zoom: 1;} /* IE < 8 */
ul .three-col-row li{width: 33.33%;margin-right:5%;f loat:left;text-align: center; 
}
ul .three-col-row li:nth-child(4n+4){margin-right:5%;float:left; 
} 
ul.three-col-row li:nth-child(3n+3){margin-right: 5%; float: right;}
.intro{margin:30px 0 0 0;}
.intro h2{margin-bottom: 15px;}
.intro p{margin-bottom: 50px;}
.intro ul.three-col-row li {max-height:350px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a couple of mistakes in your code. Here is a working fiddle to begin with:  http://jsfiddle.net/4oz6vwd6/2/

If you want to match a element with a class you should not have a space inbetween. Sometimes you did this correct sometimes not. So it shouldn't be `ul .three-col-row li:nth-child(4n+4)` but `ul.three-col-row li:nth-child(4n+4)`

The main problem though was setting `display: inline-block;`to your `ul.three-col-row li`.

I did not updated all the margins. It is now your job to figure out the margins and widths to add up to 100%.

Comment: Thanks!I gone do that! :)

Comment: @EditaZdanaviciute if the answer works for you please upvote and/or mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of CSS3 columns.

```css
.three-col-row {
    -moz-columns: 3;
    -webkit-columns: 3;
    columns: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 8px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 8px;
    column-gap: 8px;
}

li {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; 
}
h2 {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro clearself">
      <ul class="three-col-row">
        <li>
          <h2>Wat?..</h2>
          <p>Praktische en juiste informatie is een belangrijke deelsleutel tot de oplossing van rugproblemen.</p>
          <a class="button" href="advice.html">Meer info!</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h2>Hoe...</h2>
          <p>Ga zo ver mogelijk in de beweging en herhaal dit regelmatig gedurende U capaciteit.</p>
          <a class="button" href="work-out.html">Kies je sport!</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h2>Doel...</h2>
          <p>Het belangrijkste aspect is echter dat U ontdekt dat U ZELF veel kan doen om uiteindelijk uw rugklacht te vermijden, meer dan U welicht denkt.</p>
          <a class="button" href="about.html">Meer info!</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

***Note***: You can check the browser support at http://caniuse.com/#search=columns. It is safer to use vendor-prefixes for cross-browser compatibility.

.

Comment: cool, I did not think that browsers support this so good already!

Comment: @k-nut: Yes. that's good point. Interestingly only IE supports it natively, rest all browsers need vendor-prefixes. But, yes it works across all browsers.